# Some questions regarding functions and vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

I have three simple questions about whether a function form a vector space or not I hope someone can verify my intuition.

1. Do functions that vanish at end points $x = 0$ and $x = L$ form a vector space?

Yes, because any function between these points satisfies the additivity and multiplicity with a scalar property. Furthermore, we can construct a null vector which is function $f(x) = 0$ over $0$ and $L$. Lastly, $-f(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$ over this space.

2. Do periodic functions obeying $f(0) = f(L)$ form a vector space?

Yes, same as above.

3. Are vectors that obey $f(0) = 4$ form a vector space?

This one is a bit weird. Intuitively there is no inverse because we have no function that satisfies $f(0) = -4$, so all these functions do not satisfy the property of a vector space.

Can anyone check if I understand this correctly? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part also forms a linear vector space. There is a flaw in the argument above.

The requirement is that $f(0) = f(L)$. Suppose $2f = g$, then we must have $g(0) = g(L)$, which is true. $g(0)$ doesn't have to be equivalent to $f(0)$; it would still be closed under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning in part 1 is sound.  Part 2 however is not correct.  Observe that if $f(0) = f(L) = 1$ then the collection of functions with these conditions isn't closed under scalar multiplication. For instance $2f$ wouldn't be in your space since $2f(0) = 2f(L) = 2 \neq f(0)$.  Your argument in 3 is also good, but why is it weird?  I don't see it weird in the least: some collections have an inherent algebraic (or vector space) structure and some don't.  There's no promise that any set you can come up with has structure.

Comment: The only requirement on the vectors in part $2$ is that they be periodic and that they satisfy $f(0)=f(L)$, this does close under addition/scalar multiplication. Since for any function for which $f(0)=f(L)$, $cf(0)=cf(L)$ and $f(0)+g(0)=f(L)+g(L)$ if $f(0)=f(L)$ and $g(0)=g(L)$. They aren't fixed to a specific value. There is also a zero vector $f(x)=0$ which again satisfies $f(0)=f(L)=0$.